# How to update label.text in asp.net from code behind-values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

I want to popup a message everytime I click on a button.
This popup shows some information and updates its labels according to my code behind-values.

I tried different things like declare variable either *protected* or *public*:

```
Protected  test As string = "test"
'(...)
test = "another string"
```

And in .aspx file:

```
<%=test%>
```

But then I noticed I can't have `<%=%>` blocks within the attributes of server-side controls (such as `<asp:Label>`).
I tried to set the `.Text` property in the code-behind itself and it works on *Page Load*, but I want to set the `.Text` values in another function dynamically.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
       pagenumberLabel.Text = GetPagingCaptionString()
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also tried to create an hidden button and perform the click via javascript but the values are not being passed.

[.ASPx.VB]

```
Protected  fileName As string = ""

Protected Sub UpdatePopup(ByVal fileName As String)
        'fileName = "write my file name"
        ASPxLabelName.Text = fileName 
        ' this doens't work (filename="")
End Sub
' OR
Protected Sub UpdateButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click
        fileName = "write my file name"
        ASPxLabelName.Text = fileName 
        ' This works but it is not dynamic as wanted
End Sub
```

[.ASPx]

```
<dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl1" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="ShowMessageInfo"
    CloseAction="CloseButton" CloseOnEscape="True" EnableViewState="False"
    PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter"
    HeaderText="HEADER" AllowDragging="True" Modal="True"
    PopupAnimationType="Fade" PopupAction="None" Width="400px">
    <ContentCollection>
        <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl1" runat="server">
            <dx:ASPxPanel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <PanelCollection>
                    <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent1" runat="server">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Name:</td>
                                <td><dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabelName" runat="server" Text="">
                                    </dx:ASPxLabel></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" Text="Update Content"
                            style="display:none" AutoPostBack="False">
                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { ShowMessageInfo.PerformCallback(); }" />
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                    </dx:PanelContent>
                </PanelCollection>
            </dx:ASPxPanel>
        </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
    </ContentCollection>
</dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

Comment: You are not limited to Page_Load, and can set this text almost any time during the page processing on the server. Any particular problem you have with that?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't update the text label. Using `<%=%>` and in debugging mode, the value is changed but not updated.

Comment: Show us how exactly are you doing it. That is in what part of page life cycle, code you use to update the label, label markup

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Forget about `<%=%>` for a while, you can set `.Text` at code behind in any event/method you need. Does it throws any erros?

Comment: @Andrei check the update

Comment: @mafap, update looks good so far, but this is still not all. How do you use these functions? Did you subscribe to the corresponding event of the button? Do you use any update panels on the page?

Comment: @Andrei Please check again and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @zed It doesn't throw any error but the variable is not updated.

Comment: @mafap, I do not see the place where you subscribe to the buttons's click event. Also it is not clear what do you mean by "dynamic"

Comment: @Andrei "Dynamic" means that it changes everytime the button is clicked. PerformCallback is supposed to update my panel, I guess. I want to update my panel by any mean, directly or simulating a click.

Comment: why cant u use sessions.

Comment: @MHHasnain can you give an example..?

Comment: what i want to say is if for the sake of just passing value from one page to another page or panels or whatever object you have then you can use sessions.
to create session,
session("name") = something.text
to use it anywhere
something.text = session.item("name")

Comment: I'll try to figure out how sessions works

Comment: I can´t get this working. Is there anyone who can provide an elaborated answer.